# In this case, can we use 'would'?

Tags: modal-verbs

> I was amazed someone **would** know my name.
>   ([source](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?qid=5AhdF&l_cid=QNE001&l_st=1&returl=/qna/question/list.html?category_id=QNE001&))

In that situation, can *would* be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although it's a matter of context more than anything. Just taking the sentence by itself, it's better to have:

> I was amazed that someone would know my name.

If you can give more context, I can provide a better answer for you.